# how to query mongo a value with $lte and $in?

Tags: mongodb

I have a document like:

```
{
    _id:"1",
    archive:[{mark:10},{mark:20},{mark:30},{mark:40}]
},
{
    _id:"2",
    archive:[{mark:12},{mark:25},{mark:30}]
},
{
    _id:"3",
    archive:[{mark:15},{mark:18}]
}
....
```

I want to find document where archive have {mark:30} but less then mark:30.

If I use query:

```
{archive:{$elemMatch:{ mark:{$lte:30}}}
```

will get document with 2,3

If I user query:

```
{archive:{$elemMatch:{ mark:{$lte:30,$in:[30]}}}
```

will get 1,2.

how to only get document 2?
Thank you!

Comment: What if a document look like this: `{archive: [{'mark': 30}]}`? should the query return that document as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a query which would satisfy the logic

> match documents where `archive` have `{ "mark": 30 }` **AND**  `mark` is [**NOT**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/not/#op._S_not)
>   greater than 30 (same as less than or equal to 30):

```
db.collection.find({
    "archive.mark": {
        "$eq": 30,
        "$not": { "$gt": 30 }
    }
})
```

or using the [**`$and`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/#op._S_and) operator explicitly as

```
db.collection.find({
    "$and": [
        { "archive.mark": 30 },
        { "archive.mark": { "$not": {
            "$gt": 30
        } } }
    ]    
})
```

Answer (score 0):

With $elemMatch

```
db.getCollection('yourCollection').find(
{
    archive: {
        $elemMatch: {
            $and: [
             { mark: { $eq: 30 }},
             { mark: { $lte: 30 }},
             { mark: { $not: { $gt: 30 } } }
            ]
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: this still get document 1